# H2 ddl create table

Tags: sql, h2, ddl

I would like to know if it is possible to get the `H2 ddl create table` from the

```
http://localhost:5678/pecador/console/
```

I have tried `show columns from T_USER ;`

but it only shows the columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get SQL for a table `T_USER`, you can use one of two following commands in H2:

```sql
SCRIPT NODATA NOPASSWORDS NOSETTINGS TABLE T_NAME;
SELECT SQL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'T_NAME';
```

The first one also returns some unrelated elements. Actually you can dump the whole database with it, check its documentation for details:
https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#script

The second one returns only the SQL of the specified table (unless you have tables with the same name in multiple schemas, but you can add `AND SCHEMA_NAME = 'PUBLIC'` to exclude them). Note that you need to specify `'T_NAME'` in its real case, if you're using `;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE` setting it is `'t_name'`. Beware: presence of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.SQL` column in future versions of H2 is not guaranteed.